# How to transition to same route with new model?

Tags: ember.js

Trying to transition to the same route just with a different model for pagination:

```
App.ClientsIndexController=Ember.Controller.extend({
actions:{
    newPage:function(){
        var self=this;
        this.store.find('client',{"limit":5,"offset":1}).then(function(m){
            console.log(m);
            self.transitionToRoute('clients.index',m);
        },function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
});
```

End goal:
Able to paginate with Emberjs without adding new routes (e.g. page/:page_num) or fetching all the data and paginating it in Ember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to transition, you just need to change the model. So instead of this:

```
self.transitionToRoute('clients.index', m);
```

Just do this:

```
self.set('model', m);
```

And as a side note, your controller current inherits from `Ember.Controller`. You should avoid doing that, as most of the guides you'll see won't do it. Extend from `Ember.ObjectController` if your model is a single object, or from `Ember.ArrayController` if your model is an array.

Comment: Thank you, I was really stuck on this one. It makes sense if the controller/route is observing changes to the model.  Outcome will be posted soon.  The only downside I can see is if I need to run any hooks ( e.g. after model ) however in this case it should be fine.

Comment: But if the model is is part of the URL, the URL will not be updated. Nor will the afterModel or setupController hooks be called.

Comment: I've never seen `self` used in ember... But what if the transition is from a different controller? For instance, have an application-wide state that you want to send to every subroute. instead of dynamic segments, say you use query parameters to do this, essentially acting as a global variable of sorts. When you change that value, you want to change the query parameters no matter what specific subroute you may be in. then you need to be able to transitionTo 'whatever the current route is" + "new query parameters"

Comment: Query parameters are ok, however not supported in all versions of ember. The trick was not actually changing the model, but binding to other properties and observing their changes. E.g. When page number changes go fetch the new set.

Comment: torazaburo is right, this breaks the URL, breaks the back buttons, and makes you re-write all the transition error handling functionality. What if the next model isn't found? Do you have to handle the 404 redirect again? or 500 errors?  I would love to find a way to do this using the existing infrastructure of .transitionToRoute()